# Android Studio Manifest Activity Name Red underline

Tags: android, android-manifest

Android Studio Manifest Activity name highlight as Red

[image: Manifest Activity Name Red]

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String[] web = {
            "Finans",
            "Sınav",
            "Eğitim"
    };
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.home
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**CustomList.Java**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Activity names seen underline red in manifest files. When I Compile &Run in mobile phone it crashes on phone Android studio doesn't show me the error. What is wrong with this manifest I couldn't understand.

Comment: I think your activity package is different what error is showing in logcat

Comment: Show package structure

Comment: your MainActivity in which package?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity's package directory is as follows: `com.deneme2.uygulama1.MainActivity`

You're defining your base package name (`com.deneme2.uygulama1`) inside `manifest` tag. And the activities defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` should be under this base package.

Answer (score 0):

Check you package path its first line in your Activity class.

[image]

then add your Activity name at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are taking care of the following points in your project's Manifest and project package structure :

attribute :- android:name

"The name of the class that implements the activity, a subclass of Activity. The attribute value should be a fully qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.ExtracurricularActivity"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".ExtracurricularActivity"), it is appended to the package name specified in the  element. " Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check your packename in manifest and activity class. And also "CustomList.Java" class is an ArrayAdapter. You can't register ArrayAdapter as Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. So,remove "CustomList" class registration from AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, and it reeks of poor quality of android studio.

goto MainActivity.java right at the top
package com.mypackage.appname;

temporarily cut the package name line and build.  it will fail but that's alright because then you paste it back in and rebuild.

the .mainactivity red under line in the manifest will go away.